# plugin is not getting called from controller.php

Tags: plugins, joomla

**impordata.php** (controller)

```
<?php
   defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ( 'Restricted access');
   if(!class_exists('VmController'))require(JPATH_VM_ADMINISTRATOR.DS.'helpers'.DS.'vmcontroller.php');

   class VirtuemartControllerImportdata extends VmController  {

      function save() {
          $file= JRequest::getVar('csv', null, 'files','array');
          //print_r($file);

          JPluginHelper::importPlugin('importdata');
          $dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
          $ret=$dispatcher->trigger('onImportdata', array(&$file));
          //print_r($ret);
      }
   }
```

**importdata.php** plugin

```
<?php
   // no direct access
   defined('_JEXEC') or die;

   class plgImportdataImportdata extends JPlugin {       

      public function onImportdata($data) {         
          echo "**********";
          print_r($data);
          echo $data;
      }

   }
```

the plugin is not getting called from controller can you tell me  where is the mistake?
calling the plugin from controller!

Comment: What version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Do you have a `constructor` in your importdata.php for the plugin? Also, on your save function, you're not returning anything.

Comment: no i do not have constructor in importdata and in save function,ya i know my not returning anything  but at least function should get called no ...can u explain why constructor , i m new to plugins development

Comment: this is a custom plugin development

Comment: Are you saying you know that onImportdata does not run?  The echo etc are not going to be visible to you since they are not on the rendered page (unless you log to a file instead). You could add `return true;`  to the end and then you will have something to do the `print_r($ret);` on.

Comment: yes onImportdata doesnot run

Comment: You could use Joomla's built in JLog class or the native PHP error_log function for data dumps to verify the plugin is being called.

Comment: i get ans as Array () when i do print_r($ret);